# How to generate rails model inline with not null property

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I generate a rails model with not null in a object?

For example:

```
rails g model User name:string email:string
```

Name and email attributes allow to be null as default.

Have a similar question here in stackoverflow, but add to migration null:false.

What I want is something like

```
rails g model User name:string:null:false
```

and not

```
rails g model User name:string

rails g migration AddNotNullToUser null:false
```

How can i create that?

Comment: What do you mean "that's not what you want"? That's *exactly* what you want.

Comment: Could you understand what I want to mean?

Comment: You want to do something not currently supported. You would need to modify the Rails generator code to accept new options and put them in the migration.

Comment: Unfortunately, the default migration doesn't support that. [The Active Record Migrations Guide says](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) "*null and default cannot be specified via command line*" which is pretty bananas. You might be able to subclass the model generator, or [write your own](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#adding-command-line-arguments).